# Shrink div to image with percentage height

Tags: css, image, containers, jsfiddle

I want to make a containers width shrink to the size of an image. The height is given in percent relative to the browser window.

```
.img
{
    width: auto;
    height:100%;
}
.container
{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EdgKr/68/

`display:table`, like in similar cases doesnt work, because as a table cell, the image is always displayed 100% percent of its original size.

http://jsfiddle.net/EdgKr/67/

Comment: I am not sure what you are after... Is it this http://jsfiddle.net/EdgKr/59/ ?

Comment: I believe they want to have the container div match the image width as the height is decreased.  IN the fiddle, if you shrink the result panel's height, you can see the green to the right of the image.

Comment: display:table will work as it allways does, but needs to be applied to the div not the image.

Comment: It is. The image has display:inline. Its container display:table-cell. The wrap display:table.

Comment: UPDATE: I changed the fiddles a bit and added a padding, to clearify the problem. The green box should shrink to the width of the image.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing this? like what is the perfect end result for what you're trying to do?

Comment: The purpose is to create a dynamic, horizontal scrolling layout. It would always be 100% height in the brwoser and would always have the correct width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get a better solution of this problem. Please check my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Knowledge is Power</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
                -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Android = 2.3, iOS = 4 */
                -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox 1+ */
                box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, IE 8+, Opera, Safari 5.1 */
            }
            html, body
            {
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                padding:10px;
            }
            .container {
                padding:0;
                background:green;
            }
            .img {
                display: inline;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <span class="container">  
            <img class="img" src="a.jpg"/>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This still has no padding on the right. And it needs a reset for position and margin on body. Please make a fiddle.

Comment: [I made a fiddle and some corrections.](http://jsfiddle.net/PLXWq/) Does anyone know, why the container is sticking out a little bit on the bottom? It doesn't seem to affect the layout, but why is it there?

Comment: Edit: It does affect the layout. But the effect is minimal.

Comment: Dear Lord, I have fixed the issue and it now words perfectly. Please take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PLXWq/1/

Answer (score 3):

Since I asked that question, I made some progress, the sollution was incredibly simple: Just add float:left.

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.container {
    background: green;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.img {
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

The container shrinks as expected, even if the image has a percentage height.
http://jsfiddle.net/EdgKr/74/

But it's very easy to break, For example, if you add padding.
http://jsfiddle.net/EdgKr/72/

Comment: Basically thats just, what Tom said. But Toms solution didn't work, so it took me a while to find out that his answer was correct.

Comment: If someone could solve this padding problem, that would be nice. In my understanding box-sizing:border-box should be enough. Is that a bug maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of (or can think of at this moment) to have a container match the size of it's contents is by `float`ing it.  If that's an option, that might get what you're looking for. (here's your updated fiddle with `float:left;` added to `.vertainer` http://jsfiddle.net/EdgKr/61/)

Comment: Thats not, what I meant. The green container should shrink in width to match the image.

Comment: We are :)  The image is the content, and the container will shrink to fit that content if `float` is set to `left` or `right`.  You should see this in the fiddle in my answer.

Comment: No. I see a long green container. The only difference is, that the wrap now has a scrollbar.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, my mistake.  this works only when the page first loads, but does not adapt as it shrinks.  I'll keep thinking, and leave this answer in case someone is thinking the way I am - save them the trouble of being wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the container to match the images height and width, aka shrink wrap there are several options:

float:left/right, 
display:inline-block, 
display:table,
position:absolute;

each of those will cause a shrink-wrap effect if no width is specified.

I recommend using inline-block for that.

Also, it seems display:table works just fine:

http://jsbin.com/isayar/1/edit

however it is not supported in IE7 so personally i would go with inline-block instead.

Comment: Display:table does only work with 100% height. Try another value and it breaks.

Comment: If you look to the right, the container is longer than the picture.

Comment: i was able to replicate the problem. however it seems to me you havent looked at my code, which in fact works just fine. you need to remove html and body width: 100%;

Comment: I looked into your code and I scrolled the output window to the right (without any change in the code) and the green box is longer than the image. Im using the newest Firefox.

Comment: i see it now on firefox. however http://jsbin.com/isayar/1/edit which uses display:table appears to be working, at least no green is visible, neither to the right nor to the left.

Comment: here with your original code, i removed a couple things, seems to be working with chrome and ff http://jsfiddle.net/TH3B6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22997/discussion-between-lord-mord-and-user1721135)

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple

add `display: inline-block` to the `.container`

the reason why it shows green on your fiddle is display block making it fit whole width

http://jsfiddle.net/z7CT6/

Comment: The container in your fiddle doesn't shrink correctly. There is still some green showing on the right.

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug. write please your browser with version and operating system

Comment: Windows 7, Newest Firefox. Same in IE. Safari and Chrome dont show green, but have no padding to the right.